# Using Spring @Retryable with Jackson json deserialization

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, spring-retry

I'm trying to use Spring Retry for Jackson deserialization into a POJO object like so:

```
@Data
public class myPOJO {
    private String cmpStr = "test";
    private String myStr;

    @Retryable(maxAttempts=3, value=RuntimeException.class, backoff=@Backoff(delay=3000))
    @JsonProperty("jsonElement")
    private void retryableFunc(Map<String, Object> jsonElement) {
        try {
            myStr = jsonElement.get("jsonAttribute");
            if (!Objects.equals(myStr, cmpStr))
                throw new RuntimeException("Bad Response");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Bad Response");
        }
    }

    @Recover
    private void recover(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Recover triggered");
    }
}
```

MyPOJO is instantiated like this:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(Collections.singleTonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
String jsonAttribute = restTemplate.exchange(URL, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(headers), myPOJO.class).getBody().getMyStr();
```

Main app looks like:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableRetry
public class mainApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(mainApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

JSON response looks like this:

```
{
    "jsonElement": {
        "jsonAttribute": "test1"
    }
}
```

Retry is never triggered, but the exception is thrown:

`Error while extracting response for type myPOJO and content type [application/json;charset=utf-8]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Bad Response; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Bad Response`

Comment: Do you have `@EnableRetry` on some `@Configuration` class?

Comment: @GaryRussell Edited my post. Don't have ```@Configuration``` just ```@EnableRetry```

Comment: Is MyPojo a @Bean? Show how and where it is called from.

Comment: @GaryRussell Made another edit. Not quite sure if it's a bean, don't know where to declare it as such

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some basic misunderstanding. Spring Retry can only be applied to beans that Spring manages. Your POJO might be created by a Spring component (`RestTemplate`), it's not a managed `@Bean` in the application context.

You can't use annotation-based retry on objects that are not managed by the application context.

You still didn't show how you are calling the `retryableFunc` but you should, instead, call your object from some helper bean:

```java
public class MyHelper {

    @Retryable(...)
    public void validateMyPojo(MyPojo pojo, Map<...,...> jsonElement) {
        pojo.retryableFunc(jsonElement);
    }

}
```

and

```
@Bean
public MyHelper myHelper() {
    return new MyHelper();
}
```

Or, you can simply use a `RetryTemplate` to call the method.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I actually never call ```retryableFunc()``` directly. I have it annotated with ```@JsonProperty``` so that Jackson handles JSON deserialization, but I guess I can't do this and retry in one step

Comment: Ah - I didn't pay attention to the json annotation. But it's not clear why you want retry there - it will fail every time.

Comment: I basically want the same RestTemplate call to be made until the JSON response changes or max retries is reached. I guess I can just do this without Retryable

Comment: Ah that's different; if you want to keep fetching you need to put `String jsonAttribute = restTemplate.exchange(URL, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(headers), myPOJO.class).getBody().getMyStr();` in a `@Retryable` method. You also probably don't want to keep creating a new `RestTemplate` each time; you only need one for the life of the application.